# Upload/Download speed slow when connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2003

I am connecting to my company's Windows Small Business Server 2003 via VPN at home. My machine is running Windows 7 Ultimate x64. While connected to the VPN my download speed is around 200KB when tested against SpeedTest, etc.

My average download speed is 25Mb/sec when disconnected from the VPN.

I originally set the VPN up using the Network and Sharing Center feature. I just entered my VPN address and my domain username and password. I was then able to connect in to the office's domain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the properties of the VPN client there's probably an option to use the gateway on the remote network (the VPN connected network), you should unselect this option. That should force all non-VPN traffic to transit your ISP network and not the VPN network.

Comment: But what if this isn't what he wants?

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty and Haze for the answer and information.

Comment: Maybe it isn't but it certainly will resolve his speed issues to non-VPN networks.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 3):

Well the speeds are slower because when you connect to your company's VPN, there's one connection. The VPN has to connect to the destination server (download files place) then send it to the VPN, then the VPN sends it to your house. It's going to twice as many places. Plus the fact that the VPN is also using its resources to send the files/pages to you, slows it down. It's not a "direct connection." That's why when you use a proxy site it's slower. Direct connections are always fastest. Hope this helps.

Comment: So when I am browsing at home and connected to the VPN I am in fact browsing using the SBS's internet? If so, is it possible to configure the wireless router at home to route VPN traffic between the office and my home PC and anything else using my own broadband? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, on the direct connection, go to http://whatsmyip.org. remember that. Now connect again to the VPN and go to that site. If the IPs are different, you're using their internet as the outside, and yours is tunneling into the company's.

Comment: Argh.. The IP changes as soon as I connect to the VPN. Is there a solution for this? Please excuse my lack of networking/server knowledge :)

Comment: Solution is not connect to the VPN. When you are connected it's acting as a giant proxy server. What were you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: To be able to be connected to my VPN from home and not use the "offices Internet speeds". Mission accomplished.

Comment: @U4iK - not really a proxy server. A proxy server intercepts (typically) http, creates it's own http connection to the destination server and forwards the results back to the original requesting computer. VPNs in and of themselves do not typically have proxy functionality. Rather, traffic is just routed through them on its way to the destination.

Comment: I know that. But i was trying to put it in simple-to-understand terms. But it's resolved. So that's okay.

Comment: Simple-to-understand is fine. Inaccurate is not.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes. Fair e-nuff.

Comment: @Erik: I really appreciate the tips but if it's wasting your time you don't have to do this.

Comment: @U4iK_HaZe - not wasting my time at all. I truly want to improve the quality of questions and answers on the site. Helping you (and anyone else that comes along) understand how best to do this fits into that goal.

Comment: @er Well as long as it's not interfering with time spent with other people then okay.

Comment: @TxtSpk/Haze Down voting my original post just because you couldn't follow it is not cool. You can't really fault me for your misunderstanding of the original question.

Comment: Chill, bro. I wasn't the one to downvote it. But even if I was, it's my right to do so.

Comment: @Seany4 - agreed. You were likely downvoted not because it was a bad question, but because it was off-topic for Serverfault. Having questions and answers downvoted is just part of life on Stack Exchange sites. Don't worry about it.